# Modify SSRS Parameter before report runs

Tags: database, stored-procedures, reporting-services, parameters, report

I wish to modify the SSRS parameter before the report runs.

-I have two parameters (A) a ComboBox and (B) a TextValue. 
-(B) changes values based on parameter A (cascades) but a user can type specific value for B too.

however the value of B is not what i want to submit to report stored procedure. I want to take the value of B and get another value from database, assign it to B and then pass it to my actual report stored procedure.

So is there any way to modify parameter before running report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the parameter in the way you are asking, however there is a way to achieve the result you want.

You need to create a third parameter, "C". The value of C should be set from another Dataset, which takes the value of parameter "B" and returns the value from the database. You then pass the value of parameter C to your stored procedure.

If you set parameter C to be "Internal" then this will be hidden from the user running the report and they will just set parameters A and B.

Comment: That's the whole idea, i want to use the same parameter, that is prevent the current report from breaking. We have a very generic reporting structure binded with our application. But thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: It's helpful if you mention information like that in your original question in future. In this case the only other option might be to add code into the stored procedure to take the value of B and perform the lookup at the start of the procedure. If that isn't possible then I don't think you will be able to do what you are asking.

Comment: Year i should had stated that originally and also that i want to get it done with out modifying the SP. However at least now i know that these are only ways. Thanks again. Can anyone confirm that this also not possible in VBScripting